# How can I change the dialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dialog

Hi I'm trying to change the view when I do setState() in dialog in flutter. I heard that it would be fixed by wrapping contents in showDialog() by StatefulBuilder(), but it didn't work.

I don't know, but this is probably because I intend to inject contents of dialog from other class that has setState() methods.

This is `MyDialog` class:

```
class MyDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon    icon;
  final Widget  contents;
  const MyDialog(this.contents, {required this.icon, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<dynamic> dialog(context) {
    return showDialog(
      context : context,
      builder : (context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder : (context, setState) {
            return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor : const Color(0xFF082562),
              body            : contents
            );
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      color     : const Color(0xFF97A7BF),
      icon      : icon,
      onPressed : () => dialog(context)
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the class to be injected:

```
class _DialogContentsState extends State<AboutApp> {
  int _currentPageIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    const FirstPage(),
    const SecondPage(),
    const ThirdPage()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyDialog(
      Column(
        children : [
          _pages.elementAt(_currentPageIndex),

          ElevatedButton(
            child : Text('backward'),
            onPressed : () => setState(() => _currentPageIndex--)
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child : Text('forward'),
            onPressed : () => setState(() => _currentPageIndex++)
          )
        ]
      ),
      icon : const Icon(Icons.info_outline)
    );
  }
}
```

(Some parts of the code have been omitted or modified to simplify the code, so there may be something wrong, sorry.)

I'd like to switch pages when pressing the buttons.
Please tell me how can I do that.

Thanks,

Comment: sorry but you are making thing complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Firstly, I would don't prefer this pattern. Now</s> the issue is we need to update dialog content, to do that we need to trigger `StatefulBuilder`'s setState. We can pass it this way.

```dart
class MyDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon icon;
  final Widget Function(Function) contents;

  const MyDialog(
    this.contents, {
    required this.icon,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  Future<dynamic> dialog(context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (context, setState) {
              return Scaffold(
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF082562),
                  body: contents(setState));
            },
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        color: const Color(0xFF97A7BF),
        icon: icon,
        onPressed: () => dialog(context));
  }
}
```

And usecase will be

```dart
return MyDialog((setStateDialog) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      _pages.elementAt(_currentPageIndex),
      ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('backward'),
          onPressed: () => setStateDialog(() => _currentPageIndex--)),
      ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('forward'),
          onPressed: () => setStateDialog(() => _currentPageIndex++))
    ],
  );
}, icon: const Icon(Icons.info_outline));
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, and thank you for your answer! It works! But could you please tell me why you don't prefer this pattern?

Comment: Just personal opinion,  We will have this MyDialog inside another state class, so two setState can become confusing for readers. You can ignore my word, dont worry.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your opinion. It also makes sense for me  :)